# A more secure way to use key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Usually when you use key vault to encrypt and decrypt data you have to keep your AD registered app's (that has the authorization to access key vault) ClientID and ClientSecret in plain text somewhere. This seems like a security problem if someone steals the the ClientID and Secret anyone can claim they are the registered app.

Is there or can there be a more secure approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a certificate to authenticate instead of a secret.

There are three things you need to do for this approach:

1. Create a certificate to use.
2. When creating the Active Directory application that you will use to access the Key Vault, you need to pass in the certificate you created in step 1. I don't think you can do this through the portal at the minute, so you'll need to use the [New-AzureRMADApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603747.aspx) PowerShell command.
3. Use that certificate when authenticating to Key Vault. You'll need to use an [overload of the AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt459145.aspx) method that receives a ClientAssertionCertificate to do that. You can [create a ClientAssertionCertificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientassertioncertificate.aspx) by simply passing the client id and the X509Certificate2.

From [this](http://gonzowins.com/2015/10/25/manage-secrets-with-azure-keyvault-aad/) blog post you can get some some code for the first two steps.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using certificate-based with KeyVault, Azure Managed Service Identity also introduces a new way to make an Azure service become a service principal without any client app registration and client secret. Currently it is only available in preview stage for some services: Azure VM, Azure App Service, Azure Function, Azure Event Hub & Azure Service Bus. More information can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-overview

[**Update**] When ever you need to retrieve something from KeyVault, with Azure MSI you don't need a client secret. Only use `AzureServiceTokenProvider()` method to retrieve access token

In real-world deployment with automation (for example via Ansible), you can use an external certificate to store sensitive variables in Ansibe Vault and generate a 256bit chain to secure such an info. During the automation deployment, the cert is decrypted to access to these variables and perform further deployment. This way adds more encryption layer to the whole Azure deployment.